# Can't the Ross family afford their own residence?

Tags: jessie

In *Jessie*, one recurring character is Rhoda Chesterfield: the penthouse owner. This means that the Ross family are her tenants.

Surely, with all their wealth, they would be able to afford their own building, and not have to rent a penthouse suite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oops!  Even though my answer has already been accepted, I have to make a correction to it.

The Ross's apartment building appears to be a condominum, since Mrs. Chesterfield is the head of the condo board.

https://jessie.fandom.com/wiki/Rhoda_Chesterfield

So Morgan and Christina Ross probably do own their penthouse appartment and are part owners of the entire building like the other residents.  But Mrs. Chesterfield could probably find ways to make enough trouble for them they would want to move out and sell their apartment to get away from her.

---

Actually, Rhoda Chesterfield is another tenant in their building, on the floor right below the Ross penthouse - in one episode something drop's from the Penthouse terrrace onto her terrace.  Mrs. Chesterfield is also the head of the Tenants' Association in the building and sometimes tries to get the Rosses evicted.

The Rosses do own a few yachts - "Rossed at Sea" for example - and own houses outside of New York City.  In one episode the Ross kids plan to hold a fundraiser in their place at the Hamptons but they learn that their father lost the Hampton house in a card game - with Stephen Spielberg I think.

And I think that the Rosses own a few islands.  I'm sure I remember Emma mentioning their islands in an episode of *Jessie* or *Bunk'd*.

The Rosses may be rich, but they are probably not rich enough to own their own penthouse apartment, let alone the entire building it is in.

I am not an expert on NYC real estate prices, but I expect that their building would cost a few hundred million dollars, and possibly billions.  I doubt that the Rosses are rich enough to spend that much money on real estate.  Some *Jessie* fans familiar with New York should be able to recognize the building used in exterior shots, and it should be easy to look up its current value on a real estate site.

Here is a link to a list of the 20 most expensive homes for sale in the USA at the time of the list:

https://www.trulia.com/blog/most-expensive-homes-for-sale-in-america/

Number 4 is a four-bedroom 9,704 square foot Penthouse suite in New York, New York for $ 70,000,000.00.

Number 6 is a tie between two houses, one of which is a single-family house in New York City with 21,070 square feet, far smaller than the apartment building in *Jessie*, for  $ 72,000,000.00.

Number 10 is a six-bedroom 8,255 square-foot penthouse in New York City for $ 82,000,000.00.

Number 11 is a five-story 14,797 square-foot townhouse in New York City, far smaller than the apartment building, for $ 84,500,000.00.